I can't bind NavigationViewItem dynamic x:Uid in Windows App WinUI 3
I am using WinUI 3 NavigationView in my newly created Windows App application which I am trying to work on the basics with Template Studio for WinUI. I am trying to make NavigationViewItem dynamic as shown in Microsoft Blog where I can manage it with user permissions from SQL Server data.
I am new to XAML and MVVM! I understand that I will get the data for NavigationView via ViewModel. I created a couple of demo projects and tried them. I have solved the values ​​such as menu name, submenu, and icon information. However, I cannot Bind the x:Uid value. I did some research and could not find how to make a dynamic structure without using Bind in properties starting with x:.
Here are my sample codes:
<NavigationViewItem Content="{x:Bind Name}" MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}" x:Uid="{Bind Id}" >
    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="{x:Bind CategoryIcon}" />
    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
</NavigationViewItem>

new Category(){
    Id = "21",
    Name = "Menu item 7",
    CategoryIcon = "Home",
    Children = new ObservableCollection<Category>() {
        new Category() { Id = "211", Name  = "Menu item 8", CategoryIcon = "Home" },
        new Category() { Id = "212", Name  = "Menu item 9", CategoryIcon = "Home" }
    }
}

and error message:


AFAIK, you can't do bindings with x:Uid.

The WinUI3Localizer (I'm the author) might help you with this. It has its own Uid feature and lets you set/update it programmatically, meaning that you can change it dynamically.

x:Uid directive Provides a unique identifier for markup elements. For Universal Windows Platform (UWP) XAML, this unique identifier is used by XAML localization processes and tools, such as using resources from a .resw resource file. And as the error shows, must be Text. Maybe you mean the FrameworkElement.Tag Property?

Yes, after the error message, I defined the Id variable in my Category class as String, but the error was not fixed. As in other examples, I applied the Tag property. But this did not let me sleep peacefully. Thank you for your valuable answers and comments.

In general, 'x:Uid' is for localization. What are you trying to achieve, localization? or navigation?

@CenkYenikoylu Could you please explain more about your condition? You solved your problem? Maybe you yourself can answer your question.

Yes I provided a temp solution using the Tag property. Tag="BlankPage" I used the following code in my MVVM model prototype study helpers:NavigationHelper.NavigateTo="App11.ViewModels.BlankPageViewModel" What I am looking for is an industrial design. I am trying to provide user authorizations for my NavigationView and CommandBar controls. Frankly, I am looking for a MS best practice. I have created two topics regarding my research, MS Sample App and MS TemplateStudio

If I can't dynamically create the x:Uid value with the data coming from SQL. I can't create the menu dynamically with the user permissions. Then I should create the Visibility="Collapsed" value for the NavigationViewItem dynamically. Is this the right approach?

It should be x:Uid="{x:Bind Id}
Not
x:Uid="{Bind Id}
